# What does this "but" mean here?

Tags: grammar

Oh but I were in poverty!

What does this mean?
I can't find this in my dictionary.

I would appreciate it if you could quote some authoriatative source.

Comment: Please provide context.  Where does this sentence come from?  Some surrounding text and **flowerlike-blossoming-of-hidden-from-our-view** information would be helpful. Especially if you want authoritative source.

Answer (score 1):

Without the surrounding context, it means *if only I were not* although it is a fairly archaic structure.

**But** means:  *other than*, or *except for* and this is stretching the meaning to say:  If I were in another state than in poverty.

*I were* is a usage of the subjunctive (which is often difficult to see in Modern English compared to other languages, leading *some* to question its existence). It becomes necessitated by the use of *but*, particularly in the sense meaning *if*.  [See the archaic uses here for some similar examples.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive)

As I've said this usage is fairly archaic. Typically found in older dialogues such as Shakespeare, but the usage may be 19th century. [See Ngram here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=But+I+were&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBut%20I%20were%3B%2Cc0).

An alternate meaning (again without the context), would be *Oh, I had been in quite a bit of poverty at that time.*  This is also a possibility.  Only context would really tell you the difference.  But, the use of the subjunctive *were* makes me lean the other direction.

For more on the subjunctive and it's partial disappearance from Modern English, [see here.](http://alt-usage-english.org/subjunctive_supplement.html)

Comment: I will search, but it's an archaic usage. Makes it tougher.

Comment: @username901345 No, you would say "Oh but *that* I had been killed."  Give me a moment, and I will formulate a more complete answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it to be an antonym of 'Oh, that I...'.

'Oh that I were rich' means 'Oh, if only I were rich'.

'Oh but I were in poverty' says much the same thing, 'Oh but I' being the opposite of 'Oh that I'.